# How to add another Text Field in VISIO?

Tags: visio

As soon as we drag and drop any component we can see the component's name in a text field.. Similarly I want another Text Field with some numeric value like 1.0 , 2.0 to be generated and show it with the Component.

the issue is I am getting only 1 TEXT FIELD option.. Can you help me to understand this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8tp0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many text fields as you want, you need to be in the shape text editor (hit F2 first so that text edit is opened, and **then** insert fields). Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXwqpDojdB8).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not what I need.
You can look into the image I want to have more than 1 TEXTFIELD in shape sheet so when I drag and drop a component it will have 2 TEXT - One contains Name another a number

Comment: Please watch the video I mentioned above. It explains how you add two fields (so you will have two in the ShapeSheet as well). Start at 1:44 
https://youtu.be/NXwqpDojdB8?t=104